# Database connection settings with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-connection

I'm developing an application with laravel 5.2, I'm trying to connect a remote database, if I do that in the command line I have to write this:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 'remote_ip' --skip-secure-auth
```

if I write that in the command line I don't have any problem.

But now I have to do the connection with laravel, how should I write the options?

> --skip-secure-auth on my database.php file

```
'estudiantesdb' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'remote_ip',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'estudiantesdb',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root_password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: just remove the password .. set it to empty like `''`

Comment: @Demonyowh https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/352329

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p -h 'remote_ip' --skip-secure-auth
```

Here, your password is empty. So in configurations too you have to set password as empty:

```
'password' => ''
```

Your config looks like this:

```
'estudiantesdb' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'remote_ip',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'estudiantesdb',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```